# Does Okta support openid connect (OIDC) logout?

Tags: openid, openid-connect, okta

The [OIDC specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html#RPInitiated) states

> OPs supporting HTTP-based logout and OpenID Connect Discovery 1.0
>   [OpenID.Discovery] MUST provide this discovery value:
>
> end_session_endpoint REQUIRED. URL at the OP to which an RP can
>   perform a redirect to request that the End-User be logged out at the
>   OP. The end_session_endpoint is used in exactly the same manner as
>   specified in Sections 2.1 and 5 of OpenID Connect Session Management,
>   including accepting the same query parameters as defined there in
>   Section 5: id_token_hint, post_logout_redirect_uri, and state.

The [Okta OIDC Discovery Document](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html#openid-connect-discovery-document) does not contain "end_session_endpoint"

So, upon logging out of an OIDC client application, how can the user be logged out of Okta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is currently planned internally @ Okta. Source: I work there =)

**EDIT**: More information for you! We've got an open JIRA ticket for this. We'll be getting it done in the next few months (don't quote me on this though).

Comment: Would be great if you can share a link to the JIRA ticket

Comment: It's an internal instance. Do you work at okta? If so, hit me up on hipchat and I'm happy to share!

Comment: still planned? :(

Answer (score 2):

End session endpoint is not required for openid connect providers. It is required if the providers also implement optional extra specs like the one you refer to. Not sure specifically what otka implements though.